# Python 3.8 issue - print of float with 5 digits after dot - error in PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point

I am using PyCharm, Python version is 3.8

I receive the below error once I try to print e.g. 5 digits after dot for float sum variable being 3.14+2.17:

```
print(f'{test:.5f}')
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The corresponding code is:

```
test = 3.14 + 2.17
print(test)
print(f'{test:.5f}')
```

Do you have any idea why this happens, by changing "f" to "format" the issue persists. I changed Python Interpreter to 3.8 explicitly and removed 2.8 so that "f" is as well accepted in the syntax.

Thanks.

p.s. I have checked the below code on the [www.Repl.it](http://www.Repl.it) website and the print works as it should be so the issue lies within my setup...:

```
test = 3.14+2.17
print(test)
print(f'{test:.5f}')
```

Comment: can you check the actual version by running `import sys; print (sys.version)` in your code and let us know what's the output?

Comment: I have run it and the version used was.2.72... I have removed it from Add/Remove programs and now only 3.8.3 is the one version left of Python. However, PyCharm code cannot execute anymore, although the Interpreter chosen is 3.8... I will research now how to link the Python installation to PyCharm.

Comment: The most annoying types of problems :P best of luck!

Comment: @Adam.Er8 I have re-installed PyCharm and binded it to the latest Python Interpreter and now the "f" operator works as intended - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try like this bro :) <3

```
test = 3.14+2.17
print(test)
print(f'{round(test, 5)}')
```

but, better...

```
test = 3.14+2.17
print(test)
print(round(test, 5))
```